# sidesubfloat command is 'Undefined control sequence. \input'

Tags: floatrow, sidesubfloat

```
\sidesubfloat[]{\label{fig:001:a}
    
\centering

    \input{Figures/Fig_001/Fig_001_a.tex}} 

\par 

\sidesubfloat[]{\label{fig:001:b}

    \centering

    \input{Figures/Fig_001/Fig_001_b.tex} }
```

error:'Undefined control sequence. \input{Figures/Fig_001/Fig_001_b.tex} }'
I've download every usepackages(floatrow etc.), but texstudio still cannot defined 'sidesubfloat''floatsetup'command. What should I do?

Comment: Which package provides the `\sidesubfloat`  command?

Comment: @PeterWilson The `floatrow` package (in combination with the `subfig` package)

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE! Please extend your code fragment to small but complete document, which reproduce your problem. Error is not caused by showed code fragment.